# Why execution of js script in browser depends on brakepoints in debug mode?

Tags: javascript, debugging, mozilla

I have written a script in JS, and tested it in Mozilla Firefox on Ubuntu.
The code didn't work at first, so I had to debug it.

Then I found that the script was proceeding depending on where I set breakpoints in debug mode.

So if I set breakpoints as shown in the [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeXfj.png), I get `coffebrake` var's value equals 0 (but it should be 1).

And if I go into the `getVar` method, as shown in the [screenshot with going down in getVar method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D03Le.png), I get `coffebrake` equals 1, as planned.

If I use this script in normal mode, it gives results as in the first case, when I didn't set breakpoint in `getVar` method.

What is the problem? And what should I do to get proper results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're using an *asynchronous* HTTP request to get the data, but you're not waiting for it to complete before accessing `responseText`. Here's an outline of the problem:

- You're initialising the `XMLHttpRequest` using the [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) method and indicating that you want an async request with the third parameter: the rest of the code will not wait for the result of the request to complete but rather return as soon as possible.
- You're calling the `send` method without having set a status call handler. Without one you have no way of knowing when your data is ready. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send). You should really be setting the `onreadystatechange` handler before calling `send`.
- You are accessing [responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) without knowing if it's already set (the request was completed) or not. If it wasn't set, then as reported by the docs its value would be `null`. Since you're coercing the value to `Number`, it will be converted to 0, which is what you're seeing.

**Long story short**: make sure to set `onreadystatechange` before calling `send` and wait for the data to be there before querying `responseText`. Also, check for errors :)

Comment: Thanks. What is wrong if i would use synch HTTP request, that won't continue execution while don't get response? I have done it just now and everything works.

Comment: You should not use synchronous requests unless there's a very, very specific reason to do so. They badly affect the user experience. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request)